# Kotlin how to get a module path in standalone android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, path

i am working on a project that needs to reference my module path. On emulator i just use something like "D:\Captured\ext" .But what should i do when i build the app? How can i reference the module on files from root.

[i need to access this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCcaZ.png)

I  tried "..//module//file ,"//module//file" .The problem is the files i want to use are not resources so i can not move them to resources directory.I need absolute module path.

There are some questions similar to meine but actually they dont really answer so thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "On emulator i just use something like "D:\Captured\ext" ." -- an Android emulator will not be able to use Windows paths. "How can i reference the module on files from root." -- they will not exist. The Android app build process does not package into your app any arbitrary files that happen to be lying around. "so i can not move them to resources directory" -- they are files. They can be copied into a location that will result in their being packaged into the app, such as an `assets/` directory in your app module.

Comment: i got it ,thank you